# Magento 1.9.2 Responsivebannerslider sider not working

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, rwd, slider

I tried for an hours, after update the magento version 1.9.1 to 1.9.2 the Responsivebannerslider is not working.In controller terminate the process,but it's also not working.Also i tried in block index to terminate the process

```
function getResponsivebannersliderEnabled(){
  echo "Test";die;
  return Mage::getStoreConfig('generalsetting/mksresponsivegroup/enable',Mage::app()->getStore());
}
```

Please suggest me how to resolve this problem.